# i5-2520M with 2c/t showing 4 cores in VirtualBox, what does that mean?

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

I have a T420 i5-2520M with 2 cores / 4 threads, but in VirtualBox, it appears that I have 4 cores that I can use.

Does this mean that:

1. VirtualBox will be not using the 2 cores but all the 4 threads? (1 core = 1 thread)
2. VirtualBox will be using the 2 cores plus all the 4 threads that will act like a core in every 2 threads? (1 core = 2 threads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> VirtualBox will be not using the 2 cores but all the 4 threads?

It means VirtualBox will use 2 of the 4 threads your system uses.  VirtualBox doesn't specify between virtual cores (Hyperthreading) and physical cores.  VirtualBox does not distinguish the difference, this does not mean, VMMware and Hyper-V does not.

> VirtualBox will be using the 2 cores plus all the 4 threads that will
>   act like a core in every 2 threads?

That would mean VirtualBox would have access to 6 threads, based on the way you describe that statement, which wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Related: [Why does VirtualBox show more CPUs than available?](https://superuser.com/questions/540407/why-does-virtualbox-show-more-cpus-than-available?rq=1)